# LWC - apex refresh of data table from data retrieved using @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wire, refreshapex

I have a lighting web component datatable that is populated from and `@wire` call.
Below are the key snippets from my code

```js
    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import getOrderlines from '@salesforce/apex/PP_OrderController.getOrderlines';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    ..
    
    export default class Orderlines extends LightningElement {
    
       @api orderId;
      @track wiredDataResult;
    
    ...
     @wire(getOrderlines, {orderId: '$orderId'}) processOrderline({data, error}) {
            this.wiredDataResult = data;
            this.orderlines = this.wiredDataResult.listOliWrapper;
    
    ...
```

This is used to populate a datatable:

```html
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="orderLineId"
            data={orderlines}
            columns={columns}
            onsave={handleSave}
            draft-values={draftValues}
            hide-checkbox-column>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

This is all working fine.

In the `handleSave()` after sending the update to apex controller (which saves fine), I'm trying to refresh the page using `refreshApex`

```js
     refreshApex(this.wiredDataResult).then(() => {
           //Clear all draft values in the datatable
           this.draftValues = [];
     });
```

However, I'm getting error from above line as the promise is not being handled. Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘then’)“.

I've tried rewriting the @wire to :

```js
    @wire(getOrderlines, {
            orderId: ‘$orderId’
        }) processOrderline( result) {
            console.log(‘result’ + JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log(‘result.data ’ + JSON.stringify(result.data));
            this.wireResult = result;
            this.wiredDataResult = result.data;
            this.orderlines = this.wiredDataResult.listOliWrapper;
```

so that I can call the refresh apex on `wireResult` (rather than the data part only):

```js
    refreshApex(this.wireResult).then(() => {
                     //Clear all draft values in the datatable
                    this.draftValues = [];
                });
```

However with this approach the `@wire` is not populating the result object.
In the console.log message in the promise I'm getting:

> result{}
>
> result.data undefined

and thus the table is not showing on screen.

Any ideas or how to fix this?

Comment: The wire function is called first with an empty result and later with either data or error content. Make sure you allow for this.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW - this helped, I didn't know that it was called first with empty result. I was not handling the first one properly

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @PhilW for the tip 'The wire function is called first with an empty result and later with either data or error content.' I was not aware of that and I was not handling the first empty result properly.

Updated the code to

```
@wire(getOrderlines, {orderId: '$orderId'}) processOrderline(result) {

    this.wiredResult = result;
    const { data, error } = result;
    
    if (data) { ...
```

And then refresh apex to

```
refreshApex(this.wiredResult).then(() => {
    //Clear all draft values in the datatable
   this.draftValues = [];
});
```

Works now!

Answer (score 0):

If processOrderline({data, error}) is giving you data, result.data also should give you.. This is just standard deconstruction in js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

You may need to check PP_OrderController.getOrderlines and what is value of orderId

Comment: PP_OrderController.getOrderlines is unchanged between the two versions of the call.